# How to launch tests for django reusable app?

Tags: django, testing, django-testing

Can I launch tests for my reusable Django app without incorporating this app into a project?

My app uses some models, so it is necessary to provide `(TEST_)DATABASE_*` settings. Where should I store them and how should I launch tests?

For a Django project, I can run tests with `manage.py test`; when I use `django-admin.py test` with my standalone app, I get:

> Error: Settings cannot be imported,
>   because environment variable
>   DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.

What are the best practises here?

Comment: Django doesn't require a project.  What are you asking?  Did you run the the `django-admin.py test`?  What did you observe?

Comment: for django project I run tests by: manage.py test, when I use django-admin.py I get: Error: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined. I believe this have to be very simple but I stucked with this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've ended with such solution (it was inspired by solution found in django-voting):

Create file eg. 'runtests.py' in tests dir containing:

```
import os, sys
from django.conf import settings

DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)
settings.configure(DEBUG = True,
                   DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3',
                   DATABASE_NAME = os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'database.db'),
                   INSTALLED_APPS = ('django.contrib.auth',
                                     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
                                     'django.contrib.sessions',
                                     'django.contrib.admin',
                                     'myapp',
                                     'myapp.tests',))


from django.test.simple import run_tests

failures = run_tests(['myapp',], verbosity=1)
if failures:
    sys.exit(failures)
```

It allows to run tests by `python runtests.py` command.
It doesn't require installed dependencies (eg. buildout) and it doesn't harm tests run when app is incorporated into bigger project.

Answer (score 45):

The correct usage of Django (>= 1.4) test runner is as follows:

```
import django, sys
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure(DEBUG=True,
               DATABASES={
                    'default': {
                        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                    }
                },
               ROOT_URLCONF='myapp.urls',
               INSTALLED_APPS=('django.contrib.auth',
                              'django.contrib.contenttypes',
                              'django.contrib.sessions',
                              'django.contrib.admin',
                              'myapp',))

try:
    # Django < 1.8
    from django.test.simple import DjangoTestSuiteRunner
    test_runner = DjangoTestSuiteRunner(verbosity=1)
except ImportError:
    # Django >= 1.8
    django.setup()
    from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner
    test_runner = DiscoverRunner(verbosity=1)

failures = test_runner.run_tests(['myapp'])
if failures:
    sys.exit(failures)
```

DjangoTestSuiteRunner and DiscoverRunner have mostly compatible interfaces.

For more information you should consult the "Defining a Test Runner" docs:

- [DjangoTestSuiteRunner](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#defining-a-test-runner) (Django >=1.4, <1.8)
- [DiscoverRunner](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/advanced/#defining-a-test-runner) (Django >=1.8)

Answer (score 10):

For Django 1.7 it's slightly different. Assuming you have the following
directory structure for app `foo`:

```
foo
|── docs
|── foo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── tests
    ├── foo_models
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── ...
    │   └── tests.py
    ├── foo_views 
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── ...
    │   └── tests.py
    ├── runtests.py
    └── urls.py
```

This is how the Django project itself structures its tests.

You want to run all tests in `foo/tests/` with the command:

```
python3 runtests.py
```

You also want to be able to run the command from a parent directory of `tests`, e.g. by Tox or Invoke, just like `python3 foo/tests/runtests.py`.

The solution I present here is quite reusable, only the app's name `foo` must be adjusted (and additional apps, if necessary). They can *not* be installed via [modify_settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.modify_settings), because it would miss the database setup.

The following files are needed:

**urls.py**

```
"""
This urlconf exists because Django expects ROOT_URLCONF to exist. URLs
should be added within the test folders, and use TestCase.urls to set them.
This helps the tests remain isolated.
"""

urlpatterns = []
```

**runtests.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import glob
import os
import sys

import django
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line


BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..')))

# Unfortunately, apps can not be installed via ``modify_settings``
# decorator, because it would miss the database setup.
CUSTOM_INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'foo',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)

ALWAYS_INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

ALWAYS_MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)


settings.configure(
    SECRET_KEY="django_tests_secret_key",
    DEBUG=False,
    TEMPLATE_DEBUG=False,
    ALLOWED_HOSTS=[],
    INSTALLED_APPS=ALWAYS_INSTALLED_APPS + CUSTOM_INSTALLED_APPS,
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES=ALWAYS_MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES,
    ROOT_URLCONF='tests.urls',
    DATABASES={
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        }
    },
    LANGUAGE_CODE='en-us',
    TIME_ZONE='UTC',
    USE_I18N=True,
    USE_L10N=True,
    USE_TZ=True,
    STATIC_URL='/static/',
    # Use a fast hasher to speed up tests.
    PASSWORD_HASHERS=(
        'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
    ),
    FIXTURE_DIRS=glob.glob(BASE_DIR + '/' + '*/fixtures/')

)

django.setup()
args = [sys.argv[0], 'test']
# Current module (``tests``) and its submodules.
test_cases = '.'

# Allow accessing test options from the command line.
offset = 1
try:
    sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    pass
else:
    option = sys.argv[1].startswith('-')
    if not option:
        test_cases = sys.argv[1]
        offset = 2

args.append(test_cases)
# ``verbosity`` can be overwritten from command line.
args.append('--verbosity=2')
args.extend(sys.argv[offset:])

execute_from_command_line(args)
```

Some of the settings are optional; they improve speed or a more realistic environment.

The second argument points to the current directory. It makes use of the [feature of providing a path to a directory to discover tests below that directory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests).

Comment: Great answer! I added an `__init__.py` to `/tests/` to make it work.

Comment: For the most part, I was able to avoid setting up sub directories for my apps in the `tests` directory, by just setting `test_cases = '..'` instead (to allow me to follow the convention of having tests.py in the app folders). Very nice answer!

Answer (score 5):

For my reusable app([django-moderation](http://github.com/dominno/django-moderation)) I use buildout. I create `example_project`, i use it with buildout to run tests on it. I simply put my app inside of settings of `example_project`.

When i want to install all dependencies used by my project and run tests, i only need to do following:

- Run: python bootstrap.py
- Run buildout:

  bin/buildout
- Run tests for Django 1.1 and Django 1.2:

  bin/test-1.1
  bin/test-1.2

Here you can find tutorial how to configure reusable app to use buildout for deployment and tests run: http://jacobian.org/writing/django-apps-with-buildout/

Here you will find example buildout config which i use in my project:

http://github.com/dominno/django-moderation/blob/master//buildout.cfg

Comment: Thanks for useful info. Will see if this solves my problem (looks like a lot of hassle at a first glance) but might be interesting for other purposes.

Answer (score 3):

In a pure **pytest** context, to provide just enough Django environment to get tests running for my reusable app without an actual Django project, I needed the following pieces:

**pytest.ini:**

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = test_settings
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
```

**test_settings.py:**

```
# You may need more or less than what's shown here - this is a skeleton:

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    }
}

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'todo',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'base_urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'DIRS': ['path/to/your/templates'), ],
    }
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

**base_urls.py:**

```
"""
This urlconf exists so we can run tests without an actual
Django project (Django expects ROOT_URLCONF to exist.)
It is not used by installed instances of this app.
"""

from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('foo/', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

**templates/base.html:**

*If any of your tests hit actual views, your app's templates will probably be extending the project `base.html`, so that file must exist. In my case, I just created an empty file `templates/base.html`.*

I can now run `pytest -x -v` from my standalone reusable app directory, without a Django project.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I have found that if your reusable app has a file 'tests.py', then you can create a tests.py inside your project folder, and then write the following...

```
from reusableapp.tests import *
```

Django will then run these tests when you call 'python manage.py test'

Comment: I put print("***running reusableapp tests...***") at the top of the tests.py in my reusable app, so that I can see which tests are being run.